# Upload new APK to PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app published in the playstore, I'm trying to update the APK.

I've created a release in production, there are no options anywhere to upload a new apk.

I can add from library, which is just the existing apk.

Where do I upload new APKS!?

[image: playstore]

Comment: Are you using script blockers? There should be a Browse button right inside that  darker gray box.

Comment: Yea I thought so. No script blockers.. must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: Right and another refresh and the browse button is back. Must have been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can see if drag and dropping the release apk in the grey section beneath "add from library" button works for you or not.

Comment: thanks I tried that and it just downloads it to my desktop